# modify style tag python css beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Given:

```
<html>
<style>
@font-face
{font-family:"MS Mincho"}
</style>
</html>
```

How could I add `@font-face {font-family:"MS Gothic"}` to this style tag?
I'm using Beautiful soup 4 and the following code to select the style, but unsure how to add the new style after the first:

```
code = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
s = code.select('style')
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a new tag to the HTML, you can use the [`.append()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) method:

> You can add to a tag’s contents with `Tag.append()`. It works just like calling `.append()` on a Python list.

---

In your example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
<style>
@font-face
{font-family:"MS Mincho"}
</style>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.select_one("style").append('@font-face\n{font-family:"MS Gothic"}')

print(soup)
```